# How to Trigger a Macro based on Cell Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am new to code and am struggling to understand how to set up my trigger. The Spreadsheet is located here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMSgaEUw76Ri7m-7gi5CJkzy8z8HX3Y-OcR5pP9S5hI/edit?usp=sharing. I am trying to have the macro for the "History" Sheet trigger based on if A3 has the text "Yes".

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could poll every thirty minutes with something like this.

```
function callanother() {
  //call function here
}
function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "callanother").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("callanother").timeBased().everyMinutes(30).create();
  }
}
```